# Ran Java program via bash script on CLI / How do I interact with it?

Tags: centos, java, minecraft

I am trying to set up a Minecraft server on a CentOS distro, and got everything working. I made a script to execute my Java instance to get the heap right, but after initiating the script, I can no longer interact with the server (ie send commands to do extra stuff on the minecraft server).

How do I bring the server process to the foreground in my CLI terminal session that I have running via Putty so I can interact with it again?

It's only showing up when I use the ps command, and isn't listed as a job.

Contents of the script I used is listed below:

```
java -Xmx12288m -Xms2048m -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847-universal.jar nogui &
```

it's just that one line.

Script was run via the following syntax:

```
sh startserver.sh
```

Comment: Well how did you start the server? Show us your script.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that. Oops. The script is made of a single command:

java -Xmx12288m -Xms2048m -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847-universal.jar nogui &

And that's it.

Comment: Instead of running in the background with `&`, run it in a detached screen session (e.g., https://superuser.com/questions/582427/using-minecraft-server-with-screen) then attach the session when you need to interact with it.

Comment: ....That might have been my mistake the whole time. I thought that running it with & was an equivalent to screen, jobs, or something to that effect. This makes a lot more sense now.